# Reset Netstat statistics

Tags: linux, networking, netstat

Is there a method to clear the statistics of 'netstat -s' without rebooting the device?

I'm trying to determine the number of errors within a nondeterministic period of time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `netstat` tool gathers statistics from various sources provided by the kernel:

```
/proc/net/snmp
/proc/net/netstat
/proc/net/sctp/snmp # if used
```

and possibly others. As these kernel data are not reset and the `netstat` command on Linux doesn't keep a state file, it can't be asked to reset its statistics.

Fortunately, the replacement tool coming from [`iproute2`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/iproute2/) instead of deprecated [`net-tools`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/), called [`nstat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/nstat.8.html), while using about the same data sources does keep a state file (which appears to be `/tmp/.nstat.u$UID`), and by default will output only the non-zero delta since last use. Its syntax isn't the same so you'll have to adapt. If wary of breaking compatibility with other *nix, it's already done: the command parameters beside a single `-s` have often other meanings, and the statistics output between FreeBSD and Linux are quite different.

There are options to display zero deltas (`-z`/`--zero`), ignore (`-a`/`--ignore`) or not memorize (`-s`/`--noupdate`) last run to behave like `netstat -s`. There's a daemon mode (eg `-d 10`), to avoid races and count average.

To display the delta of errors counters, which appear to be all ending in `Errors` or `Errs`, that could be:

```
$ nstat -rn; sleep 50; nstat '*Errors' '*Errs'
#kernel
IpInHdrErrors                   3                  0.0
IcmpInErrors                    4                  0.0
IcmpInCsumErrors                4                  0.0
IpExtInCsumErrors               3                  0.0
```

With these errors artificially created from a network namespace using `tc qdisc add dev eth0 handle 1: root netem corrupt 10` and sending `ping`. To have average stats (last column) available, one should first run an instance in daemon mode so it can keep collecting statistics. For example:

```
nstat -d 5 -t 60
```

Of course one can also implement one's own wrapper around `netstat` to reimplement this: keep the last output somewhere and only display smartly the delta from last run.

Note: the companion command `rtacct` is about [*realm*](http://linux-ip.net/gl/ip-cref/ip-cref-node172.html) routes statistics which is usually for advanced routing (statistics).

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Comment: This answer deserves many more upvotes. Thankyou